# lock git repository if it is already in use

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, jgit

I am having a local repository ,Which has sub module repository also.If i try to access the repository from two different instance of eclipse third party tool.Will git prevent the access for second third party tool if that eclipse  repository is being by used by first third eclipse  party tool? if git does not restrict the second third party tool how to do that restriction.User is same for all third party tool

Comment: Why does one user need multiple instances of Eclipse using the same repo?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Git has protections against multiple processes writing to the same repository at the same time.

It uses lockfiles. `.git/index.lock` locks the index (aka the staging area) during `git add`. `.git/HEAD.lock` locks HEAD during `git commit`. `.git/refs/heads/master` will lock the master branch when it's being moved, and so on. Other processes will wait until the piece of the repository they need is available.

Many processes can safely read at the same time, so as many processes can be running `git log` or `git diff` simultaneously.

Most Git commands are so fast you should never notice.

Comment: will the .git/index.lock be created in check out operation?Problem is One instance is trying to check out a specific commit of a file ,at the same time if another instance trying to check out a different commit of that same file.it results in confusion.Is there any solution for this scenario.

Comment: @RenganathanSelvaraju In that case what you want is [`git-worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) to create multiple worktrees (ie. checkouts) sharing single repository. Each instance would use its own worktree. Or you can just have multiple clones.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), "[`git rev-parse --git-path`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---git-pathltpathgt) `HEAD.lock`" (one of the way to control concurrent acces) did not give the right path when run in a secondary **[worktree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59093747/6309)**.

See [commit 76a53d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76a53d640f72fc77e7e9358dfeb5df5ece56515f), [commit 3ce4721](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ce47211a6ecae0ebe241779ef7112ee21f04a74) (28 Oct 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a2b0451](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2b0451434db903975cb1dfda0eafef939ebc6db), 01 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`git_path()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76a53d640f72fc77e7e9358dfeb5df5ece56515f): handle `.lock` files correctly
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> Ever since worktrees were introduced ([Git 2.5, July 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)) , the `git_path()` function `_really`_ needed to be called e.g. to get at the path to `logs/HEAD` (`HEAD` is specific to the worktree, and therefore so is its reflog). However, the wrong path is returned for `logs/HEAD.lock`.
>
> This does not matter as long as the Git executable is doing the asking, as the path for that `logs/HEAD.lock` file is constructed from `git_path("logs/HEAD")` by appending the `.lock` suffix.
>
> However, Git GUI just learned to use `--git-path` instead of appending relative paths to what `git rev-parse --git-dir` returns (and as a consequence not only using the correct hooks directory, but also using the correct paths in worktrees other than the main one). While it does not seem as if Git GUI in particular is asking for `logs/HEAD.lock`, let's be safe rather than sorry.
>
> Side note: Git GUI `_does`_ ask for `index.lock`, but that is already resolved correctly, due to `update_common_dir()` preferring to leave unknown paths in the (worktree-specific) git directory.