# Git consider C:/ as Untracked files after removing .git/index.lock

Tags: git

That's one of the weirdest prob I've encoutered with Git. Before I deleted `index.lock` file, Git tells me that this file was used by one another process and proposed me to delete this file to continue. Since I'm using *Cygwin* with *ConEmu*, it sometimes happens that my setup begins to be a bit unstable, so I removed it. But after that, If I do a `git status` I see something like that :

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ...*some file to commit*...
        C:/
```

Of course If I try a `git add .` it will never end... I was able to add the legit modified  files into a commit but  `C:/` still there ... really weird, any idea of what to do ?

Comment: The index.lock file often contains the *next* index and it's possible that the *current* index was lost and now there's no index at all. In this case, every work-tree file will be untracked, by definition. But this suggests that your work-tree is in `/c` or `C:/` which is not a good place for a work-tree, so perhaps something else is wrong as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, no idea how it appeared but I had a symbolic link to `C:/` in my folder. Just had to delete it

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure to use [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), not git as installed as a Cygwin package.
The most recent versions of Git for Windows do manage index.lock better ([example with Git 2.25](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184041/6309))

Second, make sure there is no `.git` subfolder right under `C:\`, or Git would consider the all drive as one giant Git repository.